# Single Line Javascript method to find item with specific text then invoke a click

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to be able to click on an input that has no ID thats inside a LABEL that has no ID either.

Here is sample HTML...

```
<label>
<input type="radio" />
 item1
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" />
 item2
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" />
 item3
</label>
```

now using ONLY Javascript.  How could I go about just invoking a click on the item2 in this example?

I know that I could probably do a FOR loop through all the document.getElementsByTag("label") then check the text of each one and then probably invoke a click after I've found the specific label...

BUT i was wondering if it was posssible to do this in a very simplified method instead like using document.querySelectorAll("label") or something to this effect?  like is there noting that would allow me to do like a uh...

```
 document.querySelectorAll("label[text='item2']").click()
```

Nothing like this or anything possible?

Would need to do this on a page that already exists, so creating a Javascript Method to call/reference wouldn't work in this instance

**EDIT #1 - based off people stating its impossible for single selectors**

If its not possible to do it using a querySelectorAll and you would have to use a For-Loop/While then how would you do this in a single line?

I know sometimes you can do stuff like...

```
javascript:(function() { document.getElementById('LABELID').value+='SETVALUE'; document.querySelectorAll("Button[type='submit']")[0].click();})()
```

Is it possible to do this search and click in a single line also?

Comment: You need somehow to identify input/label. Attibute, parent elements, siblings element? Something except label text.

Comment: Unfortunately, the DOM selectors don't do a good job of this.  You really have to either create an array out of the nodes or loop through the nodes and attach the listener.  This is part of the reason libraries like jQuery are useful because they abstract this away.

Comment: you can use jquery :contains selector: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: I'm going to make a demo of how to do this without a library or looping.

Comment: I eagerly await your response Ray to learn how to do something like that

Comment: @eqiz As variant you can use this http://jsbin.com/yejeno/2/edit?js,output

Comment: `label:nth-of-type(2) input` (of course only if there aren’t any other labels on the same level inside of the parent element.)

Comment: @Alexander I can't put my own javascript inside the page since I'm doing a query on an already existing page.  So what I would need to be able to do is search and click through a simple javascript thing in a 1 line call and unfortunately i can't do that with your method.  I'll edit my post to try and make that more clear thanks though!

Comment: It sounds like a very bad idea to have `<input>`s without `name` and `value` attributes. Can't you just add them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will still need some kind of a looping. If you don't want to do a standard looping with counter variables etc. you can do something like this:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("label"), function(el) {
    if (el.innerHTML.indexOf('item3') != -1) el.click();
})
```

It is arguable whether it's better method or not, [but it works](https://jsfiddle.net/8qmpvm6x/1/)

Comment: This works perfect Yuriy!  I can fit this easily in one line also with: javascript:[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("label"), function(el) {if (el.innerHTML.indexOf('job offered') != -1) el.click();})

Comment: Could you do me a huge favor and explain what [].forEach.call does? just curious never seen that before.  Greatly Appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are no other label elements on the same level within the same parent before those shown in your example code, you can use

```
label:nth-of-type(2) input
```

selector to get the second input element.

http://jsfiddle.net/vry1n7op/

How the `:nth-of-type` pseudo class works is described f.e. here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type:

> “The :nth-of-type CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has an+b-1 siblings with the same element name before it in the document tree, for a given positive or zero value for n, and has a parent element.”

Comment: Holy crap CBroe!  that works beautifully.  Can you please explain WHY it works for future people and also myself?

Comment: But it's not finding label by text "item 2" right? It's finding second label no matter what text

Comment: Yuriy you are perfectly correct. I would need it to find specific text on the item cause they can sometimes change order I can't use this since it does only do the 2nd item on the page i Jumped way to fast, but I will up vote it as very useful information though.

Comment: @Yuriy: Correct, it works based on the occurrence of label elements within the parent element. Selecting by text content is not possible with current CSS as far as I know.

Comment: @eqiz: Added some info on the pseudo class used. If you need to match text content to find your label though, it will not help. AFAIK that is currently not possible using CSS selectors alone.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you should be able to adjust this for your needs.

```
var results = findContainsText('label','item2');

      results[0].onclick = function () {
           alert('hi');
      }

function findContainsText(querySelector, textToFind) {    
    var nodeArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(querySelector));
    var match = nodeArray.filter(function (node) {
        return node.textContent.indexOf(textToFind) > -1;
    });
    return match;
}
```

If you really just want one line and no looping...
`Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('label')).filter(function (n) {
        return n.textContent.indexOf('item2') > -1;})[0].click();`

Comment: Not having NodeList as an array is my biggest frustration with working with the DOM.  Because you can't use any array prototypes without casting to an array..

Comment: Oh you want a one liner? Let me golf this one.